# How to gt tree view in jsp/servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, tree, treeview

I need tree view in jsp page with the help of which user can select multiple tree nodes and then click on submit button where the action will be performed.
But I am not able to embedded tree view in jsp as I don't know how to embed it in jsp page.
I have worked with tree view in jFrame and I want similar feature with node selection in jsp so please help that how can I do it.
Image of jTree which i have done is looks like as shown and  want similar into my jsp page.
[image]

Comment: There's a JSP tag library here you could look at: https://www.common-controls.com/en/resources/taglib/tags/ctrl_tree.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate something that can be rendered as a tree by html.  Java will generated the structure on your servlet but you will need a 3rd party library such as jsTree on your page to render it.